# Can not install Ubuntu on HP DV7600 Pavilion

Tags: system-installation, hp

Okay I was hoping to become part of the Linux community, but it looks like that just isn't going to happen.

I have pretty much bricked my old laptop trying, so this is the last roll of the dice for me.

The original system was Vista, so now that I can no longer use that, I decided to finally bite the bullet and install something, anything, so I tried Ubuntu based upon reputation.

I have tried the following:

18.04 2 and 16.04 6. Using different USB Pen Drives and also different drives, firstly the original HDD 240gb and then tried a 480gb SSD. I can not get past the file copying stage of the install no matter what I try, which I am essentially trying blindly - hardware is a dark art to me, so perhaps this is a mountain I will not be able to climb.

I have also tried on a different computer, but got the same errors and can't afford to brick it as I use for work, so not willing to go too far with testing on that.

I just have no clue what to troubleshoot and there seems to be very little out there to bring me up to speed, with the idiots guides assuming a perfect install and everything beyond that being like this post, specific to the nth degree on spec.

The Live View works okay, well 18.04 doesn't work entirely, but 16.04 seems to work great. I had assumed it was simply the hardware setup is not capable of running linux, but that just can't be true can it?

Edit: The Error I encounter the most is number 5. I/O

Comment: Have you tried to follow the [Official Ubuntu documentation](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) in order to Install ubuntu from a windows pc ? at which task are your precisely stuck ?

Comment: Apparently the exact model I have is: DV6910ea

Comment: Lags at the Keep Language Packs then throws lots of SQASHFS Errors - Zlib, read data, block 0x19462027

Comment: Okay so the issue turned out to be corrupted files, every single download got corrupted and the checksums didn't match. The solution? Simples, downloaded the iso using my mobile data instead of the fibre connection I have.

Comment: Try by not using Rufus, for instance you have "LinuxLive USB Creator" or dozens more softwares available